# showing post request parameters in url bar

Tags: angular, typescript, http-post, angular5

I'm using angular 5 to develop my portal. All was working fine till it was in the *development* environment. But as a *production* requirement, I changed some access modifiers from `private` to `public`. And now it doesn't work in both the environments. The problem that I'm facing is I can't even *log in* now. It's now ***showing the login credentials in the URL bar even when I used POST*** for it (which was working fine before) like this -

`http://localhost:4200/?username=abcd@gmail.com&password=12345`

And I unable to login, it stays on the same page.

For reference, here is my login method -

```
login(username, password) {
    return this.http.post(this.loginUrl, { user: username, password: password})
    .map((res: any) => {
      return res;
    })
}
```

Then I reverted my changes back (`public` to `private`), but it doesn't work. Please help me to find what's going wrong.

**Update:** 
I did some workaround and found that ***problem is with HttpInterceptor***. My project is working if I remove interceptor i.e. `{ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthInterceptor, multi: true }` from the module. So, how can I make it work again?

Comment: POST method doesn't encode the response in the query string. you should use the GET or check the request body while using the post.

Answer (score 0):

This was happening due to **failure in Interceptor**. It wasn't getting my `authorization` value. So, I modified my interceptor to modify request only if user is logged in, as following -

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    this.authService = this.inj.get(UserService);
    if(this.authService.loggedIn)    // if logged in
        req = req.clone({
            setHeaders: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                authorization: this.authService.getCurrentUsername()
            }
        });

    return next.handle(req);
}
```

It is now working!